# How to get logs from Docker image running in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to debug an AWS Lambda function that's using a Docker image, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html). I'm using the stock AWS Python image: `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`

I'm able to follow the steps described in the above link to test my function locally and it works just fine:
`docker run -p 9000:8080 hello-world`, followed by `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'` in another Terminal window properly performs the function I'm expecting. However once this is running in Lambda, after successfully tagging the image and pushing it to AWS ECR, the function doesn't seem to be working and I'm not able to find any logs to debug the failed/missing executions.

I'm at a bit of a loss in terms of where these logs are stored, and/or what configuration I may be missing to get these logs into CloudWatch or something similar. Where can I expect to find these logs to further debug my lambda function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there are no technical diferences from working with docker images with lambda compated to the code as zip or in s3. As for the logs, according to AWS documentation (and this is the description directly from the docs):

*AWS Lambda automatically monitors Lambda functions on your behalf, reporting metrics through Amazon CloudWatch. To help you troubleshoot failures in a function, Lambda logs all requests handled by your function and also automatically stores logs generated by your code through Amazon CloudWatch Logs.*

*You can **insert logging statements into your code to help you validate that your code is working as expected. Lambda automatically integrates with CloudWatch Logs and pushes all logs from your code to a CloudWatch Logs group associated with a Lambda function, which is named /aws/lambda/.***

So, the most basic code would have some sort of logging within your lambda. My suggestion in this case to **troubleshoot**:

1 - Like in the image bellow, go to your lambda function and try access the cloudwatch logs directly from the console. Make sure to confirm the default region in which your function was deployed.

[image: lambda]

2 - If the logs exists (the group for the lambda function exists), the check if there are any raise exceptions from your code.

3 - If there are any errors indicating that the group log for cloudwatch doesn't exist or that the group log from the function doesnt exist, then check the configurations from your lambda directly in the console or, if you are using a framework like serverless or cloudwatch, the code structure.

4 - Finally, if everything seems ok this could be only related to one simple thing. User permissions from your account or Role permission from you lambda function (which is mostly the case for these situations).

**One thing that you should check is the basic role generated from your lambda, which ensures that you can create new log groups**

One policy example should be something like this (You can also add manually the **CloudWatch Logs** policy, the effect should be similar):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:log-group:/aws/lambda/<YOUR-LAMBDA-FUNCTION>r:*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

More related to this issue can be found here:
https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-cloudwatch-log-streams-error/

I say this because but I have used frequently docker for code dependencies with lambda, based on this first tutorial from when this feature was introduced.

https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-container-image-support/

Hopefully this was helpfull!

Feel free to leave additional comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've read that doc snippet as well, which is why I'm surprised at what I'm seeing right now. I've done all the things you've mentioned already, have a log group in CloudWatch within the same region, with no errors (no logs at all). I'm not even seeing invocations of my function. For point (4) you mentioned, are there any special permissions needed for a Docker image running in Lambda? I'm using the same role as another Lambda function I have working, but which uses a zip upload (and not a Docker image)

Comment: I should also mention that my function does have logging, which I can see when running locally 

Comment: So, out of curiosity I decided to recreate the function in the example with the node.js snippet. So, to your response: No. the most basic permissions within your lambda function would create the logs from execution. However, here is the trick part. For my test, I have chosen the option for AWS create a new role for my lambda function.  AWS attached a specific policy to my lambda. Check my edit answer again. I will add the json policy that was generated. 

Try either add this policy or create a dummy function with a new role generated automatic by AWS.

Comment: Also, when I said "No" is because by default any lambda function should have permission to write logs in cloudwatch. If your previous role does not have such policy attached my suggestion would be to add it. 

Comment: It was indeed just a permissions issue! I must've broken something by assigning a AWS role from another lambda function instead of letting the role get auto-created, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. If the answer above is the solution, please dont forget to mark as the solution. have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

For a special case when you are using serverless framework, I had to use the following to get the logs in the cloudwatch.

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event: dict, context: dict) -> dict:
   logger.info(json.dumps(event))
   # ...
   return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json_str}
```

For my case, the lambda function runs inside ecr docker container.